# Download several directories from blob azure storage in Kotlin and ZIP Them

Tags: azure, kotlin, zip, azure-web-app-service, vert.x

I am trying to download 2 directory from  blob azure storage as bytearray and compress them to zip but i got an error.
I saw in web that directory does not really exist in blob storage... I did not really understand how it works so...

Here is my code below :

```
    val dstsData = "/projections/$projectionId/inputs/datasources"
    val dstsAss = "/projections/$projectionId/inputs/assumptions"
    val dstsDL = "${inputDispatchPath}inputs.zip"

    val inputsDatasources = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        azureBatch.filesystem.downloadAsByteArray(dstsData)
    }
    val inputsAssumptions = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        azureBatch.filesystem.downloadAsByteArray(dstsAss)
    }

    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val zipOutputStream = ZipOutputStream(baos)

    val entry = ZipEntry("inputs.zip")
    entry.size = inputsDatasources.size.toLong() + inputsAssumptions.size.toShort()

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry)
        zipOutputStream.write(inputsDatasources)
        zipOutputStream.write(inputsAssumptions)
        zipOutputStream.closeEntry()
        zipOutputStream.close()
    }

    val file = ezEventBus.request(
        ServiceIORequest.WriteURLFor(
            user,
            dstsDL,
            baos.toByteArray().size.toLong()
        ),
        correlationId
    )
    file .uploader.upload(
        vertx,
        webClient,
        Buffer.buffer(baos.toByteArray()),
        baos.toByteArray().size.toLong())
```

Do you have an idea?
Thanks a lot

Regards

Comment: I suspect your path variables at top are incorrect. Can you check those once.

Comment: There are correct. Datasources and assumptions are the directories

Comment: COuld you please provide the error message in detail?

Comment: As I leared from the azure microsoft forum this is impossible to compress repertory from the blob because it does not recognize repertory.